# I am getting really long wait times getting results using googles distance matrix

Tags: php, google-distancematrix-api

I am building a small project to help find locations to a user and give the distance between the two. I found some code using the distancematrix that works like a charm, that is until I started including more locations to find the distance between the user and the locations. The code below worked great for three or four locations, but when it gets to 20 or above it will take up to eight or nine seconds. After spending a few hours reading into others projects utilizing the distance matrix this should not be the case and should be able to produce hundreds of results in seconds. By results I mean the distance from point A to point B, yet I am getting bogged down with only 20 queries.
Am I utilizing the distance matrix in an incorrect way?

Note: $orgin is outside the scope of the loop, but had the user address.
Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach ($AllC as $key=>$item){
     
     echo $item;

 $userQueryResult2 = mysqli_query($conn2, "SELECT id, addressP, cityP, StateP, zipP, milesTravel FROM `Performers` WHERE id = $item"); 
            
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userQueryResult2)){

     

    $finaelId = $row['id'];

    $AdP = $row['addressP'];
    $CityP = $row['cityP'];
    $StateP = $row['StateP'];
     $ZipP = $row['zipP'];
    $miles = $row['milesTravel'];
   

     $origin = "$AD.', '.$city.' '.$State.' '.$zip";

   $destination = "$AdP.', '.$CityP.' '.$StateP.' '.$ZipP";
     
 
  $distance_data = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.urlencode($origin).'&destinations='.urlencode($destination).'&key=Hidden');
  
  
   $distance_arr = json_decode($distance_data);
if ($distance_arr->status=='OK') {
    $destination_addresses = $distance_arr->destination_addresses[0];
    $origin_addresses = $distance_arr->origin_addresses[0];
} else {
    //Need to Send to an error page
  echo "<p>The request was Invalid. Please Contact Support</p>";
  exit();
}
   if ($origin_addresses=="" or $destination_addresses=="") {
       //Need to send to an error page
      echo "<p>Destination or origin address not found</p>";
      exit();
   }
      
    
   // Get the elements as array
   $elements = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements;
   $distance = $elements[0]->distance->text;
   $duration = $elements[0]->duration->text;
   echo "From: ".$origin_addresses."<br/> To: ".$destination_addresses."<br/> Distance: <strong>".$distance ."</strong><br/>";
   echo "Duration: <strong>".$duration."";
     echo "<br>";
        if($distance > $miles){
          array_push($tooFar, $finaelId);
          
          
      } else {
          
         array_push($alldone, $finaelId);
           
      }
    
    
    
}
 
 }
 //}
echo $countall;
exit();
```

Comment: You are making a http request everytime you run the loop. How often does $origin change? Did you try caching it?

Comment: Hi tionsys! the origin change does not change and I am using Sessions to load in the location. I purposely avoided caching as I was advised for security reasons, but it looks like I have made a big mistake. Is there still a way to avoid the multiple http request without caching it? Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I'm not 100% sure at how distance matrix works, but if it supports doing so maybe you can make a big request with all locations instead of multiple single ones. Otherwise caching is required. I would suggest caching, looks like you have to pay for requests, though. I don't see any security issues in it.